# Parsing data from a file

Tags: python, list, split, text-segmentation

I have been provided with a file containing data on recorded sightings of species, which is laid out in the format;

"Species", "\t", "Latitude", "\t", "Longitude"

I need to define a function that will load the data from the file into a list, whilst for every line in the list spiting it into three components, species name, latitude and longitude.

This is what i have but it is not working:

```
def LineToList(FileName):
    FileIn = open(FileName, "r")
    DataList = []
    for Line in FileIn:
        Line = Line.rstrip()
        DataList.append(Line)
        EntryList = []
        for Entry in Line:
            Entry = Line.split("\t")
            EntryList.append(Entry)
    FileIn.close()
    return DataList

LineToList("Mammal.txt")
print(DataList[1])
```

I need the data on each line to be separated so that i can use it later to calculate where the species was located within a certain distance of a given location.

Sample Data:

```
Myotis nattereri    54.07663633 -1.006446707
Myotis nattereri    54.25637837 -1.002130504
Myotis nattereri    54.25637837 -1.002130504
```

I am Trying to print one line of the data set to test if it is splittiing correctly but nothing is showing in the shell

**Update:**

This is the code i am working with now;

```
def LineToList(FileName):
    FileIn = open(FileName, "r")
    DataList = []
    for Line in FileIn:
        Line = Line.rstrip()
        DataList.append(Line)
        EntryList = []
        for Entry in Line:
            Entry = Line.split("\t")
            EntryList.append(Entry)
            return EntryList
    FileIn.close()
    return DataList

def CalculateDistance(Lat1, Lon1, Lat2, Lon2):

    Lat1 = float(Lat1)
    Lon1 = float(Lon1)
    Lat2 = float(Lat2)
    Lon2 = float(Lon2)

    nDLat = (Lat1 - Lat2) * 0.017453293
    nDLon = (Lon1 - Lon2) * 0.017453293

    Lat1 = Lat1 * 0.017453293
    Lat2 = Lat2 * 0.017453293

    nA = (math.sin(nDLat/2) ** 2) + math.cos(Lat1) * math.cos(Lat2) * (math.sin(nDLon/2) ** 2 )
    nC = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(nA),math.sqrt( 1 - nA ))
    nD = 6372.797 * nC

    return nD

DataList = LineToList("Mammal.txt")                
for Line in DataList:
    LocationCount = 0
    CalculateDistance(Entry[1], Entry[2], 54.988056, -1.619444)
    if CalculateDistance <= 10:
        LocationCount += 1
    print("Number Recordings within Location Range:", LocationCount)
```

When running the programme come up with an error:

```
CalculateDistance(Entry[1], Entry[2], 54.988056, -1.619444) NameError: name 'Entry' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"not working"*? Can you also give a snippet of the file so we can experiment with it? Just looking at your code I suspect the problem might be the fact that you append `Line` in `DataList` instead of `EntryList`.

Comment: `for entry in line.split("\t"): entrylist.append(entry)`  Don't use CamelCase for variable names.  Use lowercase.

Comment: @zondo PEP8 actually recommends underscore-separated lowercase for variable and function names. --not that it impacts the code's operation either way, but if you're going to correct the OP, you might want to follow the convention. That said, I use mixedCase for my variables to make my code more readable to me (mixedCase is not recommended for anything in PEP8, and it makes more sense to me to have different naming styles for functions and variables).

Comment: Its literally laid out as `"Species", "\t", "Latitude", "\t", "Longitude"` or is it `Species\tLatitude\tLongitude` (with `\t` being a tab character). If so, its a standard tad-delimited CSV (I know, weird naming...) and the `csv` module can handle it.

Comment: @Tom: Didn't I say to use lowercase?  Do you comment because you think I should have said lower_case?  I am well aware of PEP8's opinion, and in fact that is why I mentioned it.  I definitely agree that functions and variables should have different naming styles than classes.  I don't use lowercase for classes; I use CamelCase, so I believe I follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataList variable is local to the LineToList function; you have to assign to another variable at file scope:

```
DataList = LineToList("Mammal.txt")
print(DataList[1])
```

Comment: Thank you! 
It is now Printing in the Shell!

Comment: @NicoleKing: If you mark my answer as accepted, that will indicate to others that you have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I saw "Biological Sciences" in your profile and just because of that i would recommend you to take a closer look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) module.

It can be very easy:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mammal.txt', sep='\t',
                 names=['species','lattitude','longitude'],
                 header=None)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            species  lattitude  longitude
0  Myotis nattereri  54.076636  -1.006447
1  Myotis nattereri  54.256378  -1.002131
2  Myotis nattereri  54.256378  -1.002131
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a regular tab-delimited CSV that `csv.reader` can easily parse for you.

```
import csv
DataList = [row for row in csv.reader(open('Mammal.txt'), dialect='excel-tab')]
for data in DataList:
    print(data)
```

This results in

```
['Myotis nattereri', '54.07663633', '-1.006446707']
['Myotis nattereri', '54.25637837', '-1.002130504']
['Myotis nattereri', '54.25637837', '-1.002130504']
```